# assigning enum in c# with a string without using if's

Tags: c#, string, enums

I was wondering if there's an option to sign an enum, for say, color, with the options of white black and red, directly with a string "red". without using if's...
I mean i don't want to write:

```
if (string1=="red") {mycolor=Color.red};
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method from the `Enum` class:

```
mycolor = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), string1, true);
```

Comment: what is the boolean for?

Comment: You can use without bool.. see my sanswer.Bool specifies whether the operation is case-insensitive.

Comment: If the boolean parameter is `true` the parser will ignore case, i.e. `red` produces the same result as `Red`, `REd`, `RED`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Color ColorEnum = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), "YourValue");
```

or

```
Color ColorEnum = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), "YourValue",true);
```

This Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.

In second method, the **Bool specifies whether the operation is case-insensitive**